# proving {$a^ib^jc^k |\;j=i\;or\;j=k$} is not regular

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

{$a^ib^jc^k |\;j=i\;or\;j=k$} what i tried so far was first splitting it into {$a^ib^jc^k |\;j=i$} or {$a^ib^jc^k |\;j=k$} then tried to use the pumping lemma to prove it. However i couldnt get very far with it. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: If you understand why the pumping lemma works, you can solve this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Consider the intersection of your language with $a^+b^+$.